# Django custom field with sub fields

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7, django-admin, django-geoposition

I was following [this](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/08/fuzzydates-or-one-django-model-field-multiple-database-columns/) [articles](http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2008/09/clarification-for-confusion-creating.html) to have 2 columns per 1 field , so my custom field code is something like this :

```
class GeopositionField(models.Field):
    description = "A geoposition (latitude and longitude)"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 42
        super(GeopositionField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        self.name = name

        position_longitude = DecimalField(decimal_places=6,max_digits=9,default=0,blank=True)
        cls.add_to_class("position_longitude",position_longitude)

        position_latitude = DecimalField(decimal_places=6,max_digits=8,default=0,blank=True)
        cls.add_to_class("position_latitude",position_latitude)

        setattr(cls,"position_longitude",position_longitude)
        setattr(cls,"position_latitude",position_latitude)
```

And my model class is **Request** :

```
class Request(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    position = GeopositionField(null = False,default = 0)
```

( I'm modifying [django-geoposition](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition) ) Until now I have only position_latitude and position_longitude in my table (and not only "position" like it was originally)

Before

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| person_id          | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| creation_date      | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| position           | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

After

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| person_id          | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| creation_date      | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| position_longitude | decimal(9,6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| position_latitude  | decimal(8,6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

That's good, but the problem comes in django admin, and also in the shell, because if I create a "Request" object and then I try to print "position" attribute, I got a error that says the "position" attribute doesn't exists :

```
>>> from main.models import Request
>>> x = Request()
>>> x.position
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'position'
>>>
```

It works if I set position attribute in `__init__` method of Request class, but that's not the idea.

So, back to the real problem, when I try to show it in admin panel, if I call explicitly to "position" field django throws an error, curiously it works with "position_latitude" and "position_longitude"

```
class RequestAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        # fields = ['position_latitude','position_longitude] <-- this works !
        fields = ['position'] # <-- this returns error = Unknown field(s) (position) specified for Request
```

Is there a way to show "position_latitude" and "position_longitude" when RequestAdminForm only have "position" in fields list? That's what I want to achieve. Why happen the "undefined-attribute" problem ?

Comment: If I add cls.add_to_class("position",position_longitude) for example, it could work, but it tries to add a new column ...